# Get DISTINCT rows by same name and max number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Tried to think more for how to do this and searched but no solutions match what is need .
Here is the table that record a Drawing name it is dynamically depending on Drawing Name , Each Drawing inserted as Submitted in Location column and Updated to rejected and inserted with same data as Submitted with New Revision as you see in this image 
[image]

What I need is a SQL Query that Distinct the rows which has the same Drawing Name with max Revision number of this drawing name.

As you See Drawing Name1 has max revision number which is 1 this not static and also Drawing Name2 has max revision number which is 2

Any Ideas how can I do this , Sorry I'm not so good in SQL Query

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: I Think it is SQL and SQL Server Sorry

Comment: try `select drawingname,serial,max(revision),submiitdate,projectid,pdocid,depid,location from yourtable group by drawingname`

Comment: This doesn't work, as you are only grouping by drawingname, you cannot select other columns besides the max(revision).

Comment: @RicardoPeres i've just tried the query and it is working in mysql it's the same principle with group by in other databases

Comment: Again, it doesn't work, you cannot select columns that haven't been grouped by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
Select Top 1 with Ties *
From yourtable
Order by Row_number() Over(Partition by drawingname Order by revision desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by drawingname and select the maximum of revision, like this:

```
SELECT drawingname, MAX(revision)
FROM table
GROUP BY drawingname
```

Comment: Thank you This works but when i select all columns it gave me error

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM table T1
JOIN (
  SELECT drawingname, MAX(revision) maxrevision
FROM table
GROUP BY drawingname
) T2
ON T1.drawingname= T2.drawingname and T1.revision = T2.maxrevision
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
     select *,row_numver()over(partition by drawingname order by revision desc ) as rn from table1
) as t where rn=1
```